# Bind value to dropdown list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

there is such code fragment from my webpage:

```
timeout = setTimeout(function() {highlight(transfer);}, 1500);
```

I need that user could change 1500 value to other values using dropdown or check boxes. Who could help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var timeout; //populate as required from dropdown/checkboxes
timeout = setTimeout(function() {highlight(transfer);}, timeout);
```

Comment: Using jQuery: `timeout = $('#dropdownid').val()`. but make sure timeout value shoud be integer.

Answer (score 0):

### An example with simple select (not a custom deropdown)

html:

```
<select id="selectInterval" onChange="setNewValue.call(this,event)">
    <option value="">Select Interval</option>
    <option value="1500">1,5 seconds</option>
    <option value="2000">2 seconds</option>
    <option value="2500">2,5 seconds</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
var timeout;
setNewValue= function(e){
    var _v = this.value;
    if(typeof _v == "undefined" || _v == "") return;
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {highlight(transfer);}, _v);
}
```

#### [a working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Frogmouth/DNN6w/)

---

### An other Example with a simple custom Dropdown in jquery/css:

html:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <span class="evalued" rel="">Select Interval</span>
    <ul class="options">
        <li class="item" style="display:none"><a class="selected" rel="">Select Interval</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a rel="1500">1,5 seconds</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a rel="2000">2,0 seconds</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a rel="2500">2,5 seconds</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.dropdown{
    position: relative;
    width:180px;
    height:28px;
    line-height:28px;
    font-size:14px;
    padding:0 10px;
    margin:10px 0;
    font-family:"helvetica";
    background-color:#f1f1f1;
    border-color:#eee;
    cursor:pointer
}
.dropdown .selected{
    z-index:200
}
.dropdown:hover .options{
    display:block
}
.dropdown .options{
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    top:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    left:0;
}
.dropdown .options li{}
.dropdown .options li a{
    border-color:#eee;
    display:block;
    background-color:#f1f1f1;
    padding:0 10px;
}
.dropdown .options li a:hover,.dropdown .options li a.selected{
    background-color:lightblue;
    color:white;
}
```

JS:

```
var timeout;
$(function(){
    setNewValue2 = function(){
        var _v = this.rel;
        if(typeof _v == "undefined" || _v == "") return;
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            highlight(transfer);
        }, _v);
    }

    $(".dropdown a").on("click",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var _r = $(this).attr("rel");
        var _t = $(this).text();
        $(this).parents(".options").find(".item").show();
        $(this).parent().hide();
        $(this).parents(".dropdown").find(".evalued").prop({
            innerHTML : _t,
            rel : _r
        });
        setNewValue2.call(this);
    })
});
```

#### [working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Frogmouth/DNN6w/1/)

Comment: None of these answers worked for me. This value should change dynamically. There is a feature that user enters some text into text box. And, I user moves mouse over one of the words, after 1500 ms it becomes marked. If I try one of your suggestions, marking does not work. If you need all code, just ask.

Comment: ...uhmm... I really not understand what you need. So... list try for me, see this: http://jsfiddle.net/Frogmouth/7PW9A/1/

Answer (score -2):

```
<!-- Our Dropdown -->
<select id="timeout">
    <option>500</option>
    <option>1000</option>
    <option>1500</option>
</select>
<script>
    var timeout; // we will keep selected value

    $("#timeout").change(function(){
         timeout=$(this).val();
         timeout = setTimeout(function() {highlight(transfer);}, timeout);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: None of these answers worked for me. This value should change dynamically. There is a feature that user enters some text into text box. And, I user moves mouse over one of the words, after 1500 ms it becomes marked. If I try one of your suggestions, marking does not work. If you need all code, just ask.